# What if K is equal to total number of instances in KNN?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, weka, knn

my question is rather very simple i'm a little confused bout a scenario I used the value of k equal to instances the results were very common My questions is that i want to know if there are any uncommon findings in this scenario on Weka or any-other platform

Comment: I see in a lot of papers one of the things they try is "[...] kNN, with _k=n_ [...]" It's not unusual.

Answer (score 1):

kNN works in the following way

- you first calculate the distance between the new observation and all the observations in the training dataset
- then you choose k neighbours, so the k closest one in terms of distance
- at last you look at the class of these k neighbours.

Now if k is the total number

- you don't have to calculate the distance
- you don't have to choose any neighbours
- you calculate directly the proportion of the classes